# angular 2 getting hold of an element in Angular 2 for use in Material design lite

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I want to use the [Material Design Lite snackbar](http://www.getmdl.io/components/#snackbar-section) in Angular 2.

I tried to get hold of the Element in my template as the following:

**My template**

```
 <test>
     <div id="child1"> child1 <div id="child2">
      <div id="child2"> child2 <div id="child2">
       <div id="toast_error"> Error message </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</test>
```

In my component file

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef){}

ngOnInit(){
        this.show_error("something");
    }
show_error(err){
        var snackbarContainer = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#toast_error")
        var data = {
            message: 'Button color changed.',
            timeout: 2000,
            actionText: 'Undo'
        };

        snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
    }
```

I get the folowing error message. How do I get hold of the element with id `toast_error`

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'MaterialSnackbar' of null in [null]
```

PS: I have checked that `this.el.nativeElement` does give me the correct reference

## Edit

Following the answers and comments, I can now get hold of the element by using the same code inside `ngAfterViewInit`. However, I can't get the snackbar to work. Following is the updated code.

In my component file

```
   constructor(private el:ElementRef){}


    ngAfterViewInit(){
            var snackbarContainer = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#toast_error")
            var data = {
                message: 'Button color changed.',
                timeout: 2000,
                actionText: 'Undo'
            };

            console.log(snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar); //prints undefined
            //snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
        }
```

The `console.log()` command prints undefined. I have made sure that the material.min.js is loaded and checked the file, it does include `MaterialSnackbar`. How should I debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by placing the code in `ngAfterViewInit()` and also calling the `upgradeElement` as below:

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef){} 

ngAfterViewInit(){
    window.componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    var snackbarContainer =         this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#toast_error")
                    var data = {
                        message: 'Button color changed.',
                        timeout: 2000,
                        actionText: 'Undo'
                    };                           
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need direct access to DOM element then have the `ElementRef` injected:

```
constructor(ref: ElementRef) ...
```

And then access the DOM element using:

```
ref.nativeElement
```

See [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html) for further information.

Then instead of `OnInit`, try with `AfterViewInit`, to make sure the DOM is initialized before running the DOM query -> see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html).

Comment: So, I get the root element right? What do I do to get a child element (preferably by id)

Comment: if you then use it to query, does it work? the problem is that the query is made before the DOM is ready. Try with AfterViewInit, check updated answer

Comment: I updated my question. It works, but I can't get the snackbar to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template variables and `@ViewChild` to get hold of a specific element:

```
<div id="toast_error" #toastError> Error message </div>



@ViewChile('toastError') toastErrorDiv;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  toastErrorDiv.doSomething();
}
```